# How to create Mist in Blender

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes

I already tried several ways to create Mist in Blender, but it never worked 100%. I use Blender 2.78 and I want to create Mist like in this scene here. [image]
**What are the exact steps?**

---

**Here is what I have tried so far:**

I already tried this: http://blog.yamandi.com/mist-pass-blender-268-how-use-it-cycles but it simply did not work .. I dont know why.

(EDIT: I managed to fix it: Check out this graphic: [image]

Until now I already used objects successfully as Mist-creators (Volume Scatter under Volume Material). The bad thing about using Objects as Mist-creator is that they dont have an endless mist range + the mist can not be bright. Normally it appears grayish result is bad.. 
Check it out [image]
Please help

Comment: Please include some screenshots and a blend file of what you tried so far, and explain in more detail than "it did not work", otherwise it'll be hard to give you an answer that actually helps you out.

Comment: If you want to change the color of the Mist. Go to world tab under volume -> Add volume scatter -> Change color below

Comment: @dr.Sybren Thank you for the quick responce. While trying to build it up again a third time to show that I am doing exactly what is told in the Tutorial I found a way to make it work. It is different from the Tut, what I think is a bit confusing. but thanks anyways. Now my question is, how can I change this Mist color. Right now it is white. Can I change it to green for example?

Comment: @atek I know that I can change this color. But if I change it to white the mist disappear.. It can only handle dark colors I guess.. When I try to put on a Volume scatter for the whole scene it always becomes dark in the distance. Maybe you can show me an example of a blend file, where I can achieve a mist like in my aimed result, with the Volume scatter in the world tab.

Comment: check your nodes Mix -> Viewer and render layer -> composite

Comment: check this link http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=120424

Comment: AAA @Alek I already had it exactly like in the tutorial but then it did not work. Only when I made the showen changes it startet to work. YOu did not understand me there. With my graphic I wanted to show the way how it worked at my side. I hope you udnerstand now. Still I got the question how to change the mist color now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you should connect the composite node to the output of the node tree, otherwise it won't work -- that's a mistake in the tutorial.

If you want to change the mist colour, place a [ColorRamp node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/converter/color_ramp.html) in between, and change the colour of the right-most point.

[image: Example node setup]

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted, so that others also know the issue is solved.